# Function this parameter on onclick

Tags: javascript

I've some html code generated in javascript like this

```
cell.innerHTML = '<a href="#" class="sortheader" id="sortheader_'+i+'" '+ 
        'onclick="ts_resortTable(this, '+i+');return false;">' + 
        txt+'<span class="sortarrow"></span></a>';
```

I'd like to call the function ts_resortTable() but independently of the onclick event how can i generate the "this" parameter of the function?

I try to do this

```
ts_resortTable.call(document.getElementById('sortheader_'+i), i);
```

and this

```
ts_resortTable(document.getElementById('sortheader_'+i), i);
```

But it's not working

The function that i'm trying to call is this:

```
function ts_resortTable(lnk,clid) {

    //save clid in cookies
    $.cookie("clid", clid);

    //fade to table
    $('#table8k6k_progress').before('<div id="loading" style="background: #fff; position: absolute; margin-top: -25px; padding: 3px 5px; font-weight: bold;">Loading...</div>');
    $('#table8k6k_progress').fadeTo('fast',0.5, function() {
        TIMERSTART = (new Date()).getTime();
        // get the span
        var span;
        for (var ci=0;ci<lnk.childNodes.length;ci++) {
            if (lnk.childNodes[ci].tagName && lnk.childNodes[ci].tagName.toLowerCase() == 'span') span = lnk.childNodes[ci];
        }
        var spantext = ts_getInnerText(span);
        var td = lnk.parentNode;
        var column = clid || td.cellIndex;
        var table = getParent(td,'TABLE');

        // Work out a type for the column
        if (table.rows.length <= 1) return;
        var itm = ts_getInnerText(table.rows[1].cells[column]);
        //itm = itm.substr(0,7);
        sortfn = ts_sort_caseinsensitive;
        if (itm.match(/^\d{1,2}[\/-]\d{1,2}[\/-]\d{2,4}\s\d\d\W\d\d$/)) sortfn = ts_sort_date;
        if (itm.match(/^\d\d[\/-]\d\d[\/-]\d\d\d\d$/)) sortfn = ts_sort_date;
        if (itm.match(/^\d\d[\/-]\d\d[\/-]\d\d$/)) sortfn = ts_sort_date;
        if (itm.match(/^[£$]/)) sortfn = ts_sort_currency;
        if (itm.match(/^[\d\.]+$/)) sortfn = ts_sort_numeric;
        SORT_COLUMN_INDEX = column;
        var firstRow = new Array();
        var newRows = new Array();
        for (i=0;i<table.rows[0].length;i++) { firstRow[i] = table.rows[0][i]; }
        for (j=1;j<table.rows.length;j++) { newRows[j-1] = table.rows[j]; }

        newRows.sort(sortfn);

        if (span.getAttribute("sortdir") == 'down') {
            ARROW = stIsIE ? '&nbsp<font face="webdings">6</font>' : '&nbsp;&#x25BE;';
            newRows.reverse();
            span.setAttribute('sortdir','up');
        } else {
            ARROW = stIsIE ? '&nbsp<font face="webdings">5</font>' : '&nbsp;&#x25B4;';
            span.setAttribute('sortdir','down');
        }

        // We appendChild rows that already exist to the tbody, so it moves them rather than creating new ones
        // don't do sortbottom rows
        for (i=0;i<newRows.length;i++) { if (!newRows[i].className || (newRows[i].className && (newRows[i].className.indexOf('sortbottom') == -1))) table.tBodies[0].appendChild(newRows[i]);}
        // do sortbottom rows only
        for (i=0;i<newRows.length;i++) { if (newRows[i].className && (newRows[i].className.indexOf('sortbottom') != -1)) table.tBodies[0].appendChild(newRows[i]);}

        // Delete any other arrows there may be showing
        var allspans = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
        for (var ci=0;ci<allspans.length;ci++) {
            if (allspans[ci].className == 'sortarrow') {
                if (getParent(allspans[ci],"table") == getParent(lnk,"table")) { // in the same table as us?
                    allspans[ci].innerHTML = '';
                }
            }
        }

        span.innerHTML = ARROW;

        //fadeTo
        $('#table8k6k_progress').fadeTo('fast', 1);

        //remove div loading
        $('#loading').remove();
    });


    //alert("Time taken: " + ( (new Date()).getTime() - TIMERSTART ) + "ms");

}
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('sortheader_'+i)` should work; can you show us what you're trying?

Comment: Thanks Matt i tried that may be i missed something i will try again ;)

Comment: You mean, you want `this` to point to '#sort_headeri'? inside ts_resortTable?

Comment: yes that could be a solution as well Juan ;)

Comment: @Matt ok your solution is the right one but it was really tricky because the page contains a lot of data and the link with the id wasn't yet generate when i was launching the function on the document ready event. So the solution was to delay the launch of the function ;)

Comment: @Jerome: Glad you finally got it sorted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

document.getElementById('sortheader_'+i)

the link with the id wasn't yet generate when i was launching the function on the document ready event. So the solution was to delay the launch of the function ;)

Answer (score 1):

To call a function and explicitly control what `this` will be inside the function, use the function's [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Call) method

```
ts_resortTable.call(document.getElementById('sortheader_'+i), i)
```

- The above will set `this` to document.getElementById('sortheader_'+i) within the function.
- The function will also receive a single parameter, `i`

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you typed

```
$('sortheader_' + i)
```

Since this is not MooTools, you need to do this for a selector.

```
$('#sortheader_' + i)
```

You need to use a CSS selector in jQuery.

Comment: `this` will then be a jQuery object, rather than  a `HTMLElement`.

Comment: @Matt this code previously didn't included any jQuery so i don't think so ;)

Comment: @Jerome: Sorry, I meant Michaels code would make `this` a jQuery object, rather than the code already being that.

Answer (score 0):

By calling

```
onclick="ts_resortTable(this, '+i+');
```

The first parameter to the ts_resortTable function will be the `<a>` tag itelf